# is it correct "there'll be no trace that one was once two"?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

I was reading a song's lyrics and I came across this sentence that I find a bit strange, probably cause I'm not analyzing in the correct way:

> if I was just the ashes and you were the ground 
>   and under a willow they laid me down 
>   **there'll be no trace that one was once two**  
>   after I fade into you

Isn't it neccesary to add a relative pronoun like "there'll be no trace that one WHICH was once two"?

Comment: "there'll be no trace that [what is now] one [thing] was once two [things]"

Comment: Anything goes in poetry. so 'should' is almost irrelevant here.

Comment: Could you reference the piece of art that quote came from please?

Comment: Interpreting song lyrics is Off Topic, and this particular "sentence" has no relevance to normal spoken English - or even written English, outside of poetry and related forms.

Comment: @Will Hunting: But it's only marginally "English" in the first place - it's really Lit Crit. I don't understand how you can find something as obscure as this a reasonable question for ELU, but your first instinct was to say asking the word for water going down a plughole doesn't make the grade.

Comment: @Will Hunting: I won't keep on about it, honest! I just bundled up my tetchiness over two questions in two minutes, to make one "pseudo-argument". Anyway, I've cast my vote, so it's up to others how it goes from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There'll be no trace that one was once two

is correct. It means there will be no sign of the fact that one (ashes faded into ground) was once two (ashes and ground).